# convert English numbers to Arabic or Persian

Tags: javascript, angular, arabic

I'm trying to either custom a pipe to convert numbers to Arabic or Persians, or find a function to convert numbers to Arabic numbers.

I've one function but it doesn't to give me a stable result,

for example I've this date :
1400/2/2 ---> ۲/۲/۱٤۰۰

```
     arabicNumbers = ['۰', '١', '٢', '٣', '٤', '٥', '٦', '٧', '٨', '٩'];

  convertToArabic = (number) => {
    return String(number).split('').map(char => {
      if (char === '/') {
        return '/';
      } else {
        return this.arabicNumbers[Number(char)]
      }
    }
    ).join('');
  }
```

this function doesn't give a stable result, it keeps switching the numbers' order.

I hope you can help me solve this

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] which actually demonstrates how the order "keeps switching"?  I mean, I can imagine that maybe you're running into RTL and LTR issues, since Arabic is a Right-to-Left language and English is not, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989346/how-mixing-ltr-and-rtl-languages-is-managed-in-unicode), but I can't tell if this is a duplicate or not because I haven't seen the issue you're mentioning firsthand.

Comment: You're code seems to work as I expect it to: https://jsfiddle.net/qfrs415g/ I suspect jcalz is right about this being an issue with RTL text directions which has nothing to do with your posted code.

Comment: I've like 2000 row in my database but when I display them some of them only some changes orders.

Comment: how do I make sure the order direction stay the same

Comment: how to custom a pipe that convert the numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can convert Arabic or Persian numbers to Latin (English) and keep the remaining text unchanged with the following 2 simple one-liner examples:

```js
const numLatinToAr=n=>n.replace(/\d/g,d=>"٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩"[d]);
const numLatinToFa=n=>n.replace(/\d/g,d=>"۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹"[d]);


console.log(numLatinToAr("1400/2/2"));  // to Arabic
console.log(numLatinToFa("1400/2/2"));  // to Persian
```