# How to show mixed english and persian text correctly in android?

Tags: java, android, string, kotlin

I have a file name like `12343.mp4` and I want to show this text inside of a Persian text. For example I want to show something like this:

[image]

But what I get is like this:

[image]

As you can see the `.mp4` part goes to the start of the file name instead of end of it.

This is my code:

```
 fun main() {
    val fileName = "12343.mp4"
    val text = "دانلود فایل $fileName تمام شد."
    println(text)
}
```

Is it possible to fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen: [Android mixed language text - BidiFormatter on String with RTL and LTR text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20473657/295004), [How mixing LTR and RTL languages is managed in unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4989346/295004), [Android Hebrew (RTL) Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10975176/295004)

Comment: @MorrisonChang Yes. I've tested it. But it didn't make any difference in my example and texts were the same.

Comment: You should show what you've tried with detail. Your example code is rendering with plain `println` while you've tagged this question `android`.

Comment: @MorrisonChang for the sake of simplification i just posted the simplest code. I don't know that if `BidiFormatter` is used for this kind of texts or not and because of that I didn't share android code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to (Morrison Chang) for his comment.

As Ted explains in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10989502/6940373) I just had to surround the name of the file with `‎‎\u200e` character. So the code should look like this:

```
fun main() {
    val fileName = "12343.mp4"
    val seperator = "\u200e"
    val text = "دانلود فایل " + seperator + fileName + seperator + " تمام شد."
    println(text)
}
```